# Deciding between ULN2804 or ULN2803 with 74HC595

Tags: cmos, ttl, reliability, 74hc595, uln2803

I'm making a circuit with Arduino + 74HC595 + (ULN2804 / ULN2803) to drive a few 12 V Motors.

I'm trying to decide whether to use the ULN2804 or ULN2804. On testing, performance of both is fine, except Vout is around 11.46V for the ULN2804 and around 11.10V for the ULN2803, using a 12 V Supply.

On the two datasheets, almost everything seems to be same except for a few values - all related to the input of the IC:

- TTL vs. CMOS drive
- 2.7K vs. 10K input resistor
- 5V vs. 6-12V specified input voltage range

Which of the two parts is more suitable when used with the 74HC595 (CMOS) to drive 12 V motors, in the sense of long term reliability?

Or, is there no important difference between them in my application?

Comment: Vote to close. Your terse "question" gives next to no basis for understanding what you are asking about.

Comment: the higher voltage drop will cause more heat dissipation; what was the prior voltage drop? You can show the complete circuit. Did you change the PCB?

Comment: On breadboard for short term both are same. My question was simple, Which is more suitable with 74HC595 for LONG TERM RELIABLITY

Comment: 74HC595 was CMOS type & Had 2.7K Resistance, So will it Effect performance if we use ULN2803

Comment: What is the Vin for the darlington?  ULN2803 is recommended for Vin = 5V. ULN2804 is recommended for Vin = 6 to 15V.

Comment: Question Edited.

Comment: A circut diagram is ALWAYS useful. | ULN2803 and ULN2804 are essentially identical parts EXCEPT THAT the resistors in the input are suited to a specified voltage range. The TTL versus CMOS distinction is NOT related to the driver output stage but to the voltages expected at the input. The HC595 is essentially a 5V part so suited for use with the ULN2803. Using a 2804 will reduce the base drive available when using 5V inputs.

Comment: @Andy aka - Why do YOU think it is unclear what he is asking?

Comment: Can i assume that ULN2803 is SUITABLE in LONG RUN ??

Comment: I'd go with TPIC6x595, it's a '595 shift register with high current sink outputs.  6595, 6A595, 6B595, 6C595, with different current capablities.

Comment: Thanks, But none of them meeting ~500 ma current requirement

Comment: @stark Why do you think the 2803 may NOT meet the need. If Vin meets the 2803 spec and Iin-drive meets the 2803 spec and Iout/pin and Iout/all_pins meets the 2803 spec (and you haven't told us if it does) and .... , then why would it not be suitable. [Hint: looks good to me given what you have and haven't told us. Knowing the whole requirement would help].

Comment: Thanks Mr.Russell McMahon, 2803 was fine, But I'm just asking whether 2804 is more SUITABLE bcoz 74HC595, ULN2804 are CMOS And I got little lesser Voltage drop with 2804 with 12V source.

Comment: @stark You can use any of them, I'm using BOTH which are currently on stores. THE HC595 is only your trigger, so suitable or not does not matter.